# Acer 5749 laptop is overheating

Tags: 12.04, cpu, overheating

I have an Acer 5749 laptop with core i3 CPU.
I have migrated to Ubuntu 12.04 and am experiencing a serious problem:
My laptop gets really hot when I use Ubuntu. I didn't have this problem with Windows 7 on the same laptop.
I really need your help.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: An temporally solution I believe not suitable for an answer install Jupiter then set to power save mode. This slow your laptop down meaning less heat production.

Comment: always install jupiter: 
http://www.noobslab.com/2011/10/jupiter-applet-available-for-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your problem but there's an old issue with Acer machines running on an outdated BIOS. On older Acer notebooks, the fan wouldn't start on Ubuntu because it was controlled by Windows,  which led to overheating and random shutdowns. The following fixes were given:

1.) Upgrade your BIOS (which is nothing you want to do on a whim) or

2.) Play around with the fan_control script. Step-by-step instructions can be found here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1748521

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Tips from here could help: http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/09/how-to-increase-extend-battery-life-in.html

Comment: You can edit grub (sudo gedit /etc/default/grub) and change the parameters of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` from: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=powersave i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1"`. After changes save and run `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can download Lubuntu. I have an Emachine Netbook, atom processor, and it stays right arond 45 C. Critical temperature is around 95 C, I remember when I had Ubuntu, it would stay round 65, or maybe even 70 C. I would switch to Lubuntu, but you might have problems with Java or your camera, if you have one. I'm sure you can get everything figured out though.

Comment: Yeah, lubuntu is nice, had no problems with cam or java here (multiple laptops with it)